# using form array without formGroup

Tags: angular, formbuilder, formarray, vmware-clarity

I have a regular form, but I also want some of the fields to use FormGroup, as this particular array has more sensitive data and is therefore in a sub-collection(using Firestore). I added a formArray to my object, but I'm having trouble in the template. Here is my code in the ts file

```
  agency$: Observable<Agency> = this.refresh$.pipe(switchMap(refresh => this.afs
    .collection<Agency>('agencies')
    .doc<Agency>(this.agencyId)
    .valueChanges()
    .pipe(
      concatMap((agency: Agency) =>
        combineLatest([
          this.afStorage.storage
            .refFromURL('gs://agency-logos-paid-keeper')
            .child(`/${agency.agencyId}.png`)
            .getDownloadURL().catch(() => ""),
          this.afStorage.storage
            .refFromURL('gs://benefit-cards-paid-keeper')
            .child(`/${agency.agencyId}.png`)
            .getDownloadURL().catch(() => ""),
          this.afs.collection<Contacts>(`agencies/${agency.agencyId}/contacts`).get()]).pipe(
            map(([logoUrl, benefitCardPhotoUrl,contactsSnapshots]) => {
              const contacts = contactsSnapshots.docs.map(doc => {
                var contact = doc.data()
                this.contactsForm.push(this.fb.group({
                  contactId: [contact.contactId, Validators.required],
                  name: [contact.name, Validators.required],
                  email: [contact.email, Validators.email],
                  phone: [contact.phone, Validators.required],
                  type: this.fb.control("type")
                }));
              });
              console.log(contacts);
              console.log(agency);
              return {
              ...agency, logoUrl, benefitCardPhotoUrl,
                // contacts : this.contactsForm

          }
          })
        )))));

  providers = Provider;
  active: boolean;
  provider: string;
  contactsForm: FormArray = this.fb.array([]);
  // editAgenciesForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({contactsForm: this.fb.array([])})
```

and in the template

```
<div *ngIf="agency$ | async as agency">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary"
      (click)="backClicked()">Back
    </button>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary"
      (click)="archiveAgency()">Delete Agency
    </button>
  </div>
  <form clrForm (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(agency)">
    <clr-input-container>
      <label>Company Name</label>
      <input clrInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="agency.name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"  name="name" required/>
      <clr-control-error>Name is required</clr-control-error>
    </clr-input-container>
    <clr-input-container>
      <label>Phone</label>
      <input clrInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="agency.phone" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="phone"/>
    </clr-input-container>
    <clr-input-container>
      <label>Card Name</label>
      <input clrInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="agency.benefitsCardName"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"name="card"/>
    </clr-input-container>
    <clr-input-container>
      <label>Payer Name</label>
      <input clrInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="agency.payerName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="payer"/>
    </clr-input-container>
    <clr-input-container>
      <label>Daily $$ Limit</label>
      <input clrInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="agency.dailyAmountLimit" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="dailyAmountLimit"/>
    </clr-input-container>
    <clr-input-container>
      <label>Weekly $$ Limit</label>
      <input clrInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="agency.weeklyAmountLimit" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="weekylAmountLimit"/>
    </clr-input-container>
    <clr-input-container>
      <label>Weekly Limit</label>
      <input clrInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="agency.weeklyCountLimit" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="weeklyCountLimit"/>
    </clr-input-container>
    <clr-input-container>
      <label>Max Amount</label>
      <input clrInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="agency.maxTransactionAmount" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="maxTransactionAmount"/>
    </clr-input-container>
    <clr-radio-container clrInline>
      <label>Frequency</label>
      <clr-radio-wrapper>
        <input clrRadio type="radio" value="weekly" [(ngModel)]="agency.payroll.frequency" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
               name="agency.payroll.frequency"/>
        <label>Weekly</label>
      </clr-radio-wrapper>
      <clr-radio-wrapper>
        <input clrRadio type="radio" value="bi-weekly" [(ngModel)]="agency.payroll.frequency" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
               name="agency.payroll.frequency"/>
        <label>Bi-Weekly</label>
      </clr-radio-wrapper>
    </clr-radio-container>
    <clr-radio-container clrInline>
      <label>Holiday Policy</label>
      <clr-radio-wrapper>
        <input clrRadio type="radio" value="before" [(ngModel)]="agency.payroll.holidayPolicy" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="holidayPolicy"/>
        <label>Before</label>
      </clr-radio-wrapper>
      <clr-radio-wrapper>
        <input clrRadio type="radio" value="after" [(ngModel)]="agency.payroll.holidayPolicy" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="holidayPolicy"/>
        <label>After</label>
      </clr-radio-wrapper>
    </clr-radio-container>
    <clr-combobox-container>
      <label>Payday</label>
      <clr-combobox placeholder="click to display value" [(ngModel)]="agency.payroll.payday" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="payday">
        <clr-options>
          <clr-option clrValue="Sunday">Sunday</clr-option>
          <clr-option clrValue="Monday">Monday</clr-option>
          <clr-option clrValue="Tuesday">Tuesday</clr-option>
          <clr-option clrValue="Wednesday">Wednesday</clr-option>
          <clr-option clrValue="Thursday">Thursday</clr-option>
          <clr-option clrValue="Friday">Friday</clr-option>
          <clr-option clrValue="Saturday">Saturday</clr-option>
        </clr-options>
      </clr-combobox>
    </clr-combobox-container>
    <clr-combobox-container>
      <label>Start Of Week</label>
      <clr-combobox placeholder="click to display value" [(ngModel)]="agency.payroll.startOfWeek" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="startOfWeek">
        <clr-options>
          <clr-option clrValue="Sunday">Sunday</clr-option>
          <clr-option clrValue="Monday">Monday</clr-option>
          <clr-option clrValue="Tuesday">Tuesday</clr-option>
          <clr-option clrValue="Wednesday">Wednesday</clr-option>
          <clr-option clrValue="Thursday">Thursday</clr-option>
          <clr-option clrValue="Friday">Friday</clr-option>
          <clr-option clrValue="Saturday">Saturday</clr-option>
        </clr-options>
      </clr-combobox>
    </clr-combobox-container>
    <clr-combobox-container>
      <label>Provider</label>
      <clr-combobox placeholder="click to display value" [(ngModel)]="agency.provider" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="agency.provider">
        <clr-options>
          <clr-option [clrValue]="agency.provider.providerName"
                      *clrOptionItems="let provider of providers; field:'providerName'"
          >{{provider.providerName}} </clr-option>
        </clr-options>
      </clr-combobox>
    </clr-combobox-container>
    <clr-toggle-container>
      <clr-toggle-wrapper>
        <input type="checkbox" clrToggle [(ngModel)]="agency.pocTimesheetRequired" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="pocTimesheetRequired"/>
        <label>Timesheet Required</label>
      </clr-toggle-wrapper>
    </clr-toggle-container>
    <clr-input-container>
      <label>Logo</label>
    </clr-input-container>
    <img id="logoImg" [src]="agency.logoUrl" (error)="setDefaultPic($event)" alt='logoImage'
         (click)="selectImage.click()"
         width="300"/>
    <input id="inputLogoImg" type="file" accept=".png,.jpg" #selectImage (change)="uploadLogo($event)">
    <clr-input-container>
      <label for="benefitCardImg">Benefit Card</label>
    </clr-input-container>
    <img id="benefitCardImg" [src]="agency.benefitCardPhotoUrl" (error)="setDefaultPic($event)" width="300"
         (click)="selectImage2.click()"/>
    <input id="inputBcImg" type="file" accept=".png,.jpg" #selectImage2 (change)="uploadBc($event)">
    <clr-input-container formArrayName="contactsForm">
      <label>Contact Name</label>
      <input clrInput type="text" formControlName="contact.name"/>
    </clr-input-container>
    <div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
<pre>{{contactsForm.value | json}}</pre>
<!--<div class="clr-row">-->
<!--  <div class="clr-col-6">-->
<!--    <div clrForm [formGroup]="contactsForm">-->
<!--      <div clr-form-control>-->
<!--        <label><h3>Contacts</h3></label>-->
<!--        <clr-input-container>-->
<!--          <label>Contact ID</label>-->
<!--          <input clrInput type="text" formControlName="contactId"/>-->
<!--        </clr-input-container>-->
<!--        <clr-input-container>-->
<!--          <label>Contact Name</label>-->
<!--          <input clrInput type="text" formControlName="name"/>-->
<!--        </clr-input-container>-->
<!--        <clr-input-container>-->
<!--          <label>Contact Email</label>-->
<!--          <input clrInput type="email" formControlName="email"/>-->
<!--        </clr-input-container>-->
<!--        <clr-input-container>-->
<!--          <label>Contact Phone</label>-->
<!--          <input clrInput type="phone" formControlName="phone"/>-->
<!--        </clr-input-container>-->
<!--        <br>-->
<!--        <button type="button"-->
<!--                class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="editContactInfo()">Submit-->
<!--        </button>-->
<!--      </div>-->
<!--    </div>-->
<!--  </div>-->
  <div class="clr-col-6">
    <div clrForm [formGroup]="apiForm">
      <div clr-form-control>
        <label><h3>Api Info</h3></label>
        <clr-input-container>
          <label>Api ID</label>
          <input clrInput type="text" formControlName="apiId"/>
        </clr-input-container>
        <clr-input-container>
          <label>Api Secret</label>
          <input clrInput type="text" formControlName="apiSecret"/>
        </clr-input-container>
        <clr-input-container>
          <label>App Key</label>
          <input clrInput type="text" formControlName="appKey"/>
        </clr-input-container>
        <clr-input-container>
          <label>App Name</label>
          <input clrInput type="text" formControlName="appName"/>
        </clr-input-container>
        <clr-input-container>
          <label>Host Address</label>
          <input clrInput type="url" formControlName="hostAddress"/>
        </clr-input-container>
        <br>
        <button type="button"
                class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="editApiInfo()">Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<!--</div>-->
```

I'm getting an error after it compiles as follows:
vendor.js:124554 ERROR Error: formArrayName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

```
    Example:

    
<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
  <div formArrayName="cities">
    <div *ngFor="let city of cityArray.controls; index as i">
      <input [formControlName]="i">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

In your class:

this.cityArray = new FormArray([new FormControl('SF')]);
this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
  cities: this.cityArray
});
```

this is truncated...I tried adding a formGroup, which I prefer doing, but then it's not letting use push, as it can only be used as an array. I don't know how to change the code so it will let me use push.

Comment: It isn't possible up to the current version (12.x) as stated in the error message, however maybe you could use the workaround present in this [**thread**](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30264).

Comment: found the solution. Here is a direct link to a stackblitz which solved my issue.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-with-strict-input-types?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Great! I'm glad that the workaround worked for you too :)

Comment: I'm having an issue with the formControlName. it's not recognizing this: [formControlName]="name" nor this:  [formControlName]="contactsForm.name"    <clr-input-container [formGroup]="$any(contactsForm)">
      <label>Contact Name</label>
      <input clrInput type="text" [formControlName]="contacts.name"/>
    </clr-input-container>